# Consuming an asmx web service using ajax/jquery in ASP.NET?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

Hi,
I am trying to save data using web services, jquery and json. From some example on the web I got a similar code but I'm using a String instead of int:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="dialogL" title="Create a new Layer">
    <p>Enter Name:</p>
    <input id="txtValue1" type="text" size="40" />
    <p>Enter Description:</p>
    <textarea id="txtValue2" rows="4" cols="30"></textarea>
    <br />
    <input type="button" value="Create" onclick="Save()" />
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Save() { 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "testservice1.asmx/Save",
            data: "{ 'value1': " + $("#txtValue1").val() + ", 'value2': " + $("#txtValue2").val() + "}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: Success,
            error: Error
        });
    }

    function Success(data, status) {

    }

    function Error(request, status, error) {
        alert("Error: " + request.statusText);
    }
</script>
```

**ASP.NET**

```
    [WebMethod]
    public bool Save(String value1, String value2)
    {
       DoSave();
       return true;
    }
```

But this didnt work and gave me back an internal error message. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your data part, instead use

```
data: "{ value1: '" + $("#txtValue1").val() + "', value2: '" + $("#txtValue2").val() + "'}",
```

Comment: Here instead of giving quotes to the arguments i have given quotes to its corresponding value.